# Scrapy, русский язык кодируется в unicode

Tags: python, парсер, unicode, scrapy

Всем ку

Парсер записывает русский язык в unicode, а английский нет и результат получается смешанным.

Spider:

```
import scrapy

class HHspider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'vacancies'
    start_urls = [
              'https://hh.ru/search/vacancyclusters=true&area=1&enable_snippets=true&salary=&st=searchVacancy&text=python+'
                 ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for vacancy_url in response.css('div.vacancy-serp-item__info a::attr(href)').getall():
            yield response.follow(vacancy_url, callback=self.extract_skills)

        next_page = response.css('span.bloko-button-group a::attr(href)')
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def extract_skills(self, response):
        skills = response.css('div.bloko-tag-list span::text').getall()
        yield {'tags': skills}
```

output ex:

```
{"tags": ["Python", "Git", "\u041e\u041e\u041f", "Unit Testing"]}
```

Как лучше(правильней) решить данную проблему?На стадии парсинга и записи в файл или декодировать в текст потом?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не корректен, кодирование описано в документации и связано с работой фреймворка и конкретным форматом файла, в который записывается output. 
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING